# DrawImage showing a big red box

Tags: c#, drawimage

Just trying to display a picture for the game I'm making. When I run it, it shows a huge red box with a red X in it.

```
private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics background = canvas.CreateGraphics();
    background.DrawImage(GameGraphics.DogStatsBox, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the graphics instead of using the e.Graphics object? The X means there was an exception or error in the drawing code. Try debugging and setting breakpoints to see what the values of GameGraphics.DogStatsBox is, I'm guessing its null.

Comment: And that aside, you *have* to dispose of that object. You're breaking the entire drawing chain because you keep the surface locked past the paint event, and the next try would result in a lock up until the GC triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, the `Graphics` object can't find the Picture you're trying to display. The big red X is a placeholder. Set your Image first, then try to draw it.